# Sentencia JOIN con 3 tablas y usando GRUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```sql
SELECT preguntas.id,
       preguntas.id_tipo_respuesta,
       group_concat(opc_multiples.opciones order by opc_multiples.opciones asc) AS Opciones 
from opc_multiples,
     preguntas,
     cat_productos 
where preguntas.id_tipo_respuesta = 3 
and opc_multiples.id_pregunta = preguntas.id 
and preguntas.id_prod_asign = cat_productos.id 
group by opc_multiples.id_pregunta 
order by cat_productos.nombre_producto asc
```

me retorna los siguientes datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esta segunda consulta

```sql
SELECT preguntas.id,
       preguntas.pregunta,
       cat_productos.nombre_producto,
       preguntas.id_tipo_respuesta 
FROM preguntas,
     cat_productos 
where preguntas.id_prod_asign = cat_productos.id;
```

que me retorna lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he intentado y no he logrado es la consulta para que el As Opciones de la primera consulta lo pueda visualizar todo en la segunda solo cuando aplique, he intentado con join pero no lo he conseguido.

Comment: No queda clara tu duda, si la puedes explicar mejor te lo agradeceré

Comment: @Aprendiz Necesito hacer una consulta que me muestra los datos de opciones de la primera consulta en la segunda pero solo cuando aplique, cuando el id_tipo_respuesta =3 y los demas los mande en null, lo he intentado con join pero no lo consigo

Comment: Necesitas mostrar la estructura de tus tablas, datos de prueba y resultados esperados con base en esos datos de prueba. Sin eso, es dificil que te ayuden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De esta forma harías `JOIN` entre las diferentes tablas.

Considera usar siempre JOINs explícitos, porque dan más claridad a las consultas. Creo que se te dificultaba sacar los JOIN porque estabas usando JOINs implícitos (basados en `WHERE`).

Aquí he usado alias cortos para las tablas, de modo que la consulta sea más legible. Y si observas he añadido al `GROUP BY` las columnas que podrían repetirse, para dar un estándar FULL GROUP BY a tu consulta, algo que MySQL ignora por lo general y que no es una buena práctica.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.pregunta,
       cp.nombre_producto,
       p.id_tipo_respuesta, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(om.opciones ORDER BY om.opciones ASC) AS Opciones 
FROM preguntas p
    INNER JOIN cat_productos cp ON p.id_prod_asign = cp.id
    INNER JOIN opc_multiples om ON om.id_pregunta = p.id 
WHERE p.id_tipo_respuesta = 3 
GROUP BY om.id_pregunta, p.pregunta, cp.nombre_producto
ORDER BY cp.nombre_producto ASC;
```

No tengo un set de datos para probar la consulta, pero debería funcionar así. Si hay algún problema me dices en comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Me quedo con esto:

> el As Opciones de la primera consulta lo pueda visualizar todo en la
>   segunda solo cuando aplique,

esa definición la puedo llegar a entender de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT preguntas.id,
       preguntas.pregunta,
       cat_productos.nombre_producto,
       preguntas.id_tipo_respuesta,
       T.Opciones 
       FROM preguntas,
            cat_productos
       left join (
                    SELECT preguntas.id,
                           group_concat(opc_multiples.opciones order by opc_multiples.opciones asc) AS Opciones 
                           from opc_multiples,
                                preguntas,
                                cat_productos 
                           where preguntas.id_tipo_respuesta = 3 
                           and opc_multiples.id_pregunta = preguntas.id 
                           and preguntas.id_prod_asign = cat_productos.id 
                           group by opc_multiples.id_pregunta
            ) T
            ON T.preguntas.id = preguntas.preguntas.id
       where preguntas.id_prod_asign = cat_productos.id;
```

Esto (creo yo) responde a lo que estás planteando, pero entiendo es una consulta innecesariamente compleja.

Comment: Esta consulta me arroja un error el ON

Comment: @Jack, si faltaba el segundo alias `ON T.preguntas.id = preguntas.preguntas.id`