# Sentencia JOIN usando GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

la estructura de mis tablas son

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no todas las preguntas tienen opc_multiples y las opciones multiples las ligo a las preguntas correspondientes y las muestro con la siguiente consulta

```sql
SELECT opc_multiples.id_pregunta,group_concat(opc_multiples.opciones order by opc_multiples.opciones asc) AS Opciones from opc_multiples,preguntas where preguntas.id_tipo_respuesta = 3 and opc_multiples.id_pregunta = preguntas.id  group by opc_multiples.id_pregunta ;
```

y me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito y no he podido obtener es mostrar todas las preguntas sean o no de opcion multiple y si son mostrar el AS Opciones y cuando no que aparezca null, es con un join pero no logro hacerlo

Comment: left join tenes que usar

Comment: Creo que se resolvería con [la misma consulta que te indicaba aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329525/29967), cambiando `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN` en aquellas tablas donde podría haber nulos. A veces, cuando se usa `GROUP_CONCAT` conviene usar también `COALESCE` para evitar también que un nulo en el grupo afecte a todos los otros.

Comment: @A.Cedano Funcionó para mostrar solo las preguntas con multiples con sus opciones en group by, asi ya lo tenia, pero no he podido lograr mostrar todas las preguntas y las opciones de las preguntas multiples cuando aplique y cuando no que muestre nulos

Comment: Ya no sé si esta pregunta es relativa a la anterior o si es otro problema. En cualquier caso, para que te muestre las coincidencias que no tienen filas en la tabla del `JOIN` sólo tienes que usar un `LEFT JOIN` o un `RIGHT JOIN`, dependiendo del lado en que esté la tabla que podría tener no coincidentes. Revisa la respuesta dada, que va por ese camino, al parecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo:

```
create table preguntas(
  id_pregunta int,
  pregunta varchar(32)
);

create table opciones_multiples(
    id_opcion int,
      id_pregunta int,
  descripcion varchar(32)
);


insert into preguntas values (1, 'Pregunta 1 tiene opciones');
insert into preguntas values (2, 'Pregunta 2 no tiene opciones');
insert into preguntas values (3, 'Pregunta 3 tiene opciones');
insert into preguntas values (4, 'Pregunta 4 no tiene opciones');
insert into preguntas values (5, 'Pregunta 5 tiene opciones');

insert into opciones_multiples values(1, 1, 'rojo');
insert into opciones_multiples values( 2, 1, 'amarillo');
insert into opciones_multiples values(3, 1, 'azul');

insert into opciones_multiples values(4, 3, 'lunes');
insert into opciones_multiples values(5, 3, 'miercoles');
insert into opciones_multiples values(6, 3, 'viernes');

insert into opciones_multiples values(7, 5, 'neo');
insert into opciones_multiples values(8, 5, 'trinity');
insert into opciones_multiples values(9, 5, 'morpheo');
```

Como bien mencionan en los comentarios, debes usar un left join de modo que aunque no exista el registro correspondiente en la tabla de opciones multiples, te devuelve el null que necesitas. Verifica bien las columnas y el orden de las tablas. La consulta sería:

```
select pre.id_pregunta, group_concat(op.descripcion) as opciones
from preguntas pre
left join  opciones_multiples op on pre.id_pregunta = op.id_pregunta
group by (pre.id_pregunta)
```

Y este el resultado:

```
id_pregunta     opciones
1               rojo,amarillo,azul
2               (null)
3               viernes,lunes,miercoles
4               (null)
5               morpheo,neo,trinity
```

Aqui tienes el [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6fa67/1) para practicar.