# Consulta mySql de tres tablas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, base-de-datos

quisiera que me ayudaran con lo siguiente de antemano gracias.

Tengo 3 tablas "conductor", "transito", "reporte".

Cada tabla tiene su id primaria, solo reporte tiene id primaria y 2 llaves foraneas que es idConductor y idOficial.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al ingresar por ejemplo idConductor = 3 me de como resultado todos los reportes que tengan como llave foranea idConductor = 3, los datos del conductor y ademas los datos del oficial que le hizo el reporte.

Ejemplo un reporte creado por el oficial "idOficial = 7" al conductor "idConductor 3" da como resultado el reporte con "idReporte = 10".

Despues el oficial "idOficial = 9" realiza el reporte al conductor "idConductor 3" da resultado como reporte "idReporte = 11"

Quiero hacer algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM conductor, transito, reporte WHERE idConductor = 3;
```

Como resultado esperaria algo asi:

> ["idReporte"10"idOficial"7"idConductor"3],["idReporte"11"idOficial"9"idConductor"3]

(Cada id con sus respectivos campos y datos).

Comment: Esto se hace con `JOIN`. Investiga como funciona, intenta un código y nos dices lo que no has entendido, los problemas que tienes, etc y te ayudaremos. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de JOIN con tres tablas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55667/29967) y [aquí tienes otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329525/29967).

Comment: Puedes dejar tus tablas? para así poder ver lo que tu vez

Answer (score 0):

Eso se realizar con un inner join para poder unir las tres tablas y que busque segun relación.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Para mas información te dejo un link de w3School para que lo veas como funciona.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp